# Strange GWT Error with external jar on server side

Tags: gwt

I want to use a external jar (Apache Mahout) on the server side of my GWT Applicatopn. 
As far as i know using external jars on the server side shouldn't cause an error. Only on the client side but when i try to run the code i get the following error:
"no source code is available for de.unimannheim.paniscus.server..."
Whats wrong here ?

Please help me i need to solve this for my thesis

---

Hi guys i created now an collbaorative.gwt.xml where i inherited all classes from apache mahout that are used within de.unimannheim.paniscus.server.collaborative but it's still not working. Sorry i'm helpless whats wrong here ?

Comment: In your `*.gwt.xml` file do you have an `<inherts>` entry for the library?  I think that you should *not* have one.

Comment: add inherits tag in your ".gwt.xml" file for those classes. and u can take help from this link http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-incubator/wiki/PathsHandlingFAQ

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Dusty Campbell, you should not inherit the jar in the *.gwt.xml. The `<inherits>` tag in the `*.gwt.xml` specifies gwt-modules which should be inherited. So only client-side-compatible code can be inherited.

Citation from the gwt docs: "`<inherits name="logical-module-name" />` : Inherits all the settings from the specified module as if the contents of the inherited module's XML were copied verbatim. Any number of modules can be inherited in this manner"
see also: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideInheritingModules

My guess is that you (by mistake) use a class from the "de.unimannheim.paniscus.server" package in client-side or shared code. Even just an import statement (`import de.unimannheim.paniscus.server.*`) will cause this exception.

Comment: Well Steffinchen you're right i use a class from the server package. But i have to use this class because i need information from this class (recommendations). How can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Sorry it took me this long to answer, I was away on vacation... Hope it still helps. In GWT, on the client-side you can only use code which gwt can translate into javascript. Everything else goes to the server side. You cannot access server-side code directly from the client-side (e.g. use it in a client-side class) so you have to make a request to the server to get the information you need. [This page](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/2.2/DevGuideServerCommunication.html) explains how those requests can be made.