# GWT: Run a JAR in the server side

Tags: gwt, jar, webserver

I am starting to develop a web app with GWT, and so far everything is great. However I am a little lost in finding an example or pointers, in how to do a call to a JAR in the server side. Basically what I want is to click in a button, and launch a task in the server side to run a JAR and after get the answer from the server to see if everything was OK.

I have found this question in the site

[Strange GWT Error with external jar on server side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991386/strange-gwt-error-with-external-jar-on-server-side)

But no clue about how was the development. Thanks a lot.

Please for those expers out there, I also accept any other suggestions for the design, maybe this thing I am trying to do is a horrible idea.

Edit: I have access to the code of the application, but it is not a simple Java application, it is has extensive use of SQL and SOAP, which I don't think GWT won't be able to compile into javascript to run in the client.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest including this Jar on Classpath of your project and invoke it's actions programatically, provided of course that you know the API of this library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I have updated my question. I have access to the code of the Java app, however it has extensive use of SQL and SOAP, and I don't think GWT will be able to compile it. That's why I want to run it in the server.

Comment: But wait a minute, I thought the Jar is handled on the server side, so what does it have to do with GWT Compiler?

Comment: Wotjek thanks a lot for the answer, I think my question was confusing, what I meant is what is explained in this tutorial https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC Thanks a lot Wotjek for your time.

Comment: Yep, RPC is basically what I was trying to suggest. It is calling server side code using GWT RPC built-in mechanism.